# how to remove blue background when image is double clicked in kiosk mode

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am currently making use a web app on 42 inch touch screen enabled TV to play card matching games. I am currently facing an issue whereby when user taps on the card image, there will occur a blue background that covers the card image or the entire background.

I have attached the image isse below for your perusal:

[image]

The current issue I am facing happens under 2 conditions:

1.) when user taps too quickly

2.) when user uses the entire hand on the screen and taps repeatedly.

I have tried searching for solutions however, I have not encountered others facing such an issue.

Hence, I would like to ask for some help on how to rectify the following issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to image's CSS or to the element that holds that number 44:

```css
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Comment: i can also put that element inside the css style for html, body{...} right?

Comment: @Luke yes, you can add this CSS rule to the whole body if you like, but then none of (possible) text won't be selectable

Comment: alright, understood. But i do wonder if it will affect the focus of the input box? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```css
::selection {
background:transparent; 
}
::-moz-selection {
background:transparent; 
}
::-webkit-selection {
background:transparent; 
}
```